# asio::read() takes really long time, no proble with asio::write

Tags: c++, sockets, tcp, network-programming, boost-asio

I'm writing simple synchronous SMTP and POP3 client. The problem is with reading the server response. It's being read correctly, although it takes really long time, like a minute. I've looked at the communication with wireshark and I get the response immediately, but somehow this line is throttling (debugger check)

> boost::asio::read(socket, receiveBuffer, boost::asio::transfer_all(), error);

Am I doing something wrong? Do You know any solution to that?

Comment: How is `receiveBuffer` defined ? SMTP is a protocol which is based on new-line delimiter. You should rather use `read_until` overload which takes delimiter to read as much data as you need.

Comment: `boost::asio::streambuf receiveBuffer;` this is the definition. @rafix07

Comment: `transfer_all` for `streambuf` returns in two cases: `64k` bytes of data was read (it is default value for reading data in single operation), or error occured, for example the second side closed connection, and as a result in this case you have some read data with `EOF` as the error. Your call of `write` works, because `write` takes some buffer and has its length, so it knows how many bytes must be sent. If you don't know how much data has to be read, use `read_until`, read until `\r\n` sequence appears in coming data.

Comment: @rafix07 Thank You, it works like a charm! One more question. How should I synchronize the communication, I use `boost::asio::write` multiple times. I must wait for the response, but `read_until()` doesn't do the job. How to keep it synchronized? Now it seems that I'm shooting to the server without giving him time to think.

Comment: Ok, it works. I were using `read_until` too many times.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> `transfer_all` for `streambuf` returns in two cases: 64k bytes of data was read (it is default value for reading data in single operation), or error occured, for example the second side closed connection, and as a result in this case you have some read data with `EOF` as the error. Your call of `write` works, because `write` takes some buffer and has its length, so it knows how many bytes must be sent. If you don't know how much data has to be read, use `read_until`, read until *\r\n* sequence appears in coming data.

@rafix07